# Excel macro for copying worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a macro that copies a worksheet x times (entered via user form) and saves each under a new name, but as I have never programmed in Visual Basic, don't really know how to proceed.

I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: [This](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) will teach you the basics on creating a userform. [This](https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-save-workbook/) will teach you how to save a workbook in VBA. [This](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/for_next.php) will teach you how to loop. Stack Overflow isn't a code for me site you need to post what you have done so far to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start with code, when you gain more experience, you may want to move into forms.

See code below,

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

For I = 1 To 10

    Sheets("Sheet name you want to copy").Select
    Sheets("Sheet name you want to copy").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

Next I

End Sub
```